# Php array manipulation custom

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to get Below object in to this format how can i get this i want some one to guide me.

This method is for generating number of variants from the product based on its options.

I have tried in static variable in the array loop but it ended up with missing 2-4 variants

**Example OutPut** which i need

```
Yellow, M, 1Gb
Yellow, M, 2GB
Yellow, S, 1GB
Yellow, S, 2GB
Yellow, L, 1GB
Yellow, L, 2GB


Green, M, 1Gb
Green, M, 2GB
Green, S, 1GB
Green, S, 2GB
Green, L, 1GB
Green, L, 2GB
```

**Object Data**

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "variantID": 1,
            "option_name": "Yellow",
            "imageID": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "variantID": 1,
            "option_name": "Green",
            "imageID": 2
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "variantID": 2,
            "option_name": "M"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "variantID": 2,
            "option_name": "S"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "variantID": 2,
            "option_name": "L"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "variantID": 3,
            "option_name": "1GB"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "variantID": 3,
            "option_name": "2GB"
        }
    ]
]
```

Sorry: not good in english

Comment: data is a string json ?

Comment: Yes  its an JSON Object @miglio

Answer (score 0):

Plugin: https://github.com/bpolaszek/cartesian-product

```
use function BenTools\CartesianProduct\cartesian_product;

$data = [
    'color' => [
        'yellow',
        'green'
    ],
    'size' => [
        'm',
        's',
        'l',
    ],
    'ram' => [
    '1 gb',
    '2 gb',
]
];

foreach (cartesian_product($data) as $combination) {
    printf('color: %s - size: %s - ram: %s' . PHP_EOL, $combination['color'], $combination['size'],$combination['ram']);
}
```

OutPUT:

```
color: yellow - size: m - ram: 1 gb
color: yellow - size: m - ram: 2 gb
color: yellow - size: s - ram: 1 gb
color: yellow - size: s - ram: 2 gb
color: yellow - size: l - ram: 1 gb
color: yellow - size: l - ram: 2 gb
color: green - size: m - ram: 1 gb
color: green - size: m - ram: 2 gb
color: green - size: s - ram: 1 gb
color: green - size: s - ram: 2 gb
color: green - size: l - ram: 1 gb
color: green - size: l - ram: 2 gb
```